# Render Custom PDF From Custom Html

Tags: cakephp, pdf

I have a list of products in my `DB`. For every product I have to generate a PDF (the receipt) whose template/layout differs from others.
I was thinking to put the html `layout/template` in a column of the products DB table. But how to render it in `CakePhp`? I have to render some variables...

Comment: Rendering a PDF view is not default functionality (AFAIK) you might want to checkout a plugin to handle this e.g. https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf

Comment: The problem is not the pdf, but the ortodox way to extract the template of the product and render some variables. I would not have separate .ctp for every product...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tackled a similar issue where I've had a Page model where individual pages had vastly different layouts.

I would create View templates, in your View folder, for each variant layout for your products and then have a `pdf_view_template` column in your database that stores the template to use. Then in your ProductsController set the view:-

```
if (!empty($data['Product']['pdf_view_template'])) {
    $this->view = $data['Product']['pdf_view_template'];
}
```

This would allow templates to be reusable as well as giving you the ability to have a default template to fall back on. It also avoids you having to store loads of templating data in the database.

This seems like a more Cake way of doing this.